# Function issue while returning a value

Tags: vb.net, function

So, I am trying to make a Function method work but some issues came up and I am not able to solve them. I've used breakpoint and I found that this is making a loop and one of the code lines isn't called. This is the method:

```
Private Function SendToRecycle(filename As String) As Boolean
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to sent it to recycle bin?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        Return "True"
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(filename, FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, FileIO.RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin)
    ElseIf MsgBox("Are you sure you want to sent it to recycle bin?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.No Then
        Return "False"
    End If
    Return SendToRecycle
End Function
```

What it does is simple, if user select option Yes it should return true and sent that file to recycle bin and write into my database, if not it will return true and write into my database without delete that added file. 
But what is happening is, if I click Yes it will return True but not calling the operation to delete the file...

Do you have any ideia how can I solve my problem?

Comment: `Return` exits the procedure before that later method is called.  [Also likely sockpuppet alert](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37950134/1070452)

Comment: Put the Return after the line that starts My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile ...

Comment: If I do that, it will delete the file but not return true @ChicagoMike

Comment: @Plutonix Did you flag it for moderator attention? Leaving a link here in the comments doesn't do any good---put it in the flag dialog's textbox!

Comment: What you are talking about? @CodyGray

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
Private Function SendToRecycle(filename As String) As Boolean
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to sent it to recycle bin?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(filename,FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, FileIO.RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin)
        Return True
    ElseIf MsgBox("Are you sure you want to sent it to recycle bin?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.No Then
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: On return it will give me an error `Expression expected`

Comment: I've tried it and it does not work. Basically it does not read the return true and delete the file without read that line